# Website isolation in IIS shared environemnt?

Tags: iis-7, website, hacking

How do I ensure website isolation in a shared environment on IIS 7 ?

basically I host multiple websites and I do not want one getting hacked, ending up in all getting hacked.

anyways I can ensure this?

Answer (score 1):

Web site isolation in a shared hosting environment is consistent with all general security isolation recommendations for Internet Information Services 7 (IIS7). In particular, it is recommended to:

- Use one application pool per Web
  site.
- Use a dedicated user account as an
  identity for the application pool.
- Configure anonymous user identity to
  use the application pool identity.
- Ensure that FastCGI impersonation is
  enabled in the Php.ini file.

Answer (score 0):

This article talks about setting up [isolated application pools](http://www.adopenstatic.com/cs/blogs/ken/archive/2008/01/29/15759.aspx), which will do what you want. The best way to protect multiple websites is to run each website under a different identity with the lowest required privileges (IE: same privileges as the Network Service account). That way you can use standard 
 file permissions and group policy to restrict access for each user individually. Many hosting  control panels such as [Plesk](http://www.parallels.com/products/plesk/) and [cPanel](http://www.cpanel.net/) will use this sort of permissions model to make sure the system is secure.